# MySQL fixing index so possible keys is not null on left join

Tags: mysql, optimization, left-join, database-indexes

This question follows on from the [problem posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367286/mysql-multiplying-subquery-results) when i run explain I on my query

```
SELECT u_id, SUM(counts.s_count * tablename.weighted) AS total FROM tablename 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT a_id, s_count FROM tablename WHERE u_id = 1) counts
  ON tablename.a_id = counts.a_id
GROUP BY u_id ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 0,100;
```

I get the response

```
+----+-------------+--------------------+-------+---------------+-----------+---------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table              | type  | possible_keys | key       | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+--------------------+-------+---------------+-----------+---------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | tablename          | index | NULL          | a_id      | 3       | NULL | 7222350| Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | [derived2]         | ALL   | NULL          | NULL      | NULL    | NULL |    37  |                                              |
|  2 | DERIVED     | tablename          | ref   | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY   | 4       |      |    37  | Using index                                  |
+----+-------------+--------------------+-------+---------------+-----------+---------+------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
```

the table is created with

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tablename (
  u_id INT NOT NULL,
  a_id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL,
  s_count MEDIUMINT NOT NULL,
  weighted FLOAT NOT NULL,
  INDEX (a_id),
  PRIMARY KEY (u_id,a_id)
)ENGINE=INNODB;
```

how can I change the index or query to get it to make use of the key more effectively? Once the database grows to a 7 million rows the query takes about 30 seconds

**edit**
 
which can be created with dummy data using

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tablename ( u_id INT NOT NULL,   a_id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL,s_count MEDIUMINT NOT NULL,  weighted FLOAT NOT NULL,INDEX (a_id), PRIMARY KEY (u_id,a_id))ENGINE=INNODB;
INSERT INTO tablename (u_id,a_id,s_count,weighted ) VALUES (1,1,17,0.0521472392638),(1,2,80,0.245398773006),(1,3,2,0.00613496932515),(1,4,1,0.00306748466258),(1,5,1,0.00306748466258),(1,6,20,0.0613496932515),(1,7,3,0.00920245398773),(1,8,100,0.306748466258),(1,9,100,0.306748466258),(1,10,2,0.00613496932515),(2,1,1,0.00327868852459),(2,2,1,0.00327868852459),(2,3,100,0.327868852459),(2,4,200,0.655737704918),(2,5,1,0.00327868852459),(2,6,1,0.00327868852459),(2,7,0,0.0),(2,8,0,0.0),(2,9,0,0.0),(2,10,1,0.00327868852459),(3,1,15,0.172413793103),(3,2,40,0.459770114943),(3,3,0,0.0),(3,4,0,0.0),(3,5,0,0.0),(3,6,10,0.114942528736),(3,7,1,0.0114942528736),(3,8,20,0.229885057471),(3,9,0,0.0),(3,10,1,0.0114942528736);
```

Comment: run the explain query and check how many rows it is traversing

Comment: if you scroll to the right of the response in the first row it has the number of rows as 7M which is the size of the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hardly force MySQL to use an index for the join with results of a subquery, but  you can try to speed up the grouping by using a coverage index (an index that has enough data not to fetch the row it references):

Try to add an composite index (u_id, a_id, weighted)

And you will probably need to give MySQL a hint to use the index:

```
SELECT u_id, SUM(counts.s_count * tablename.weighted) AS total
FROM tablename USE INDEX(Index_3)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT a_id, s_count FROM tablename WHERE u_id = 1) counts
  ON tablename.a_id = counts.a_id
GROUP BY u_id ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 0,100;
```